# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class - info.hoang8f.widget.FButton

Tags: java, android, xml

Running into the error "Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class", I am new to Java and would appreciate some help!

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context="com.jackmills.urbansportsfitness.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnTraining"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id = "@+id/btnExercises"
                android:text="Excercises"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width = "0dp"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:shadowEnabled="true"
                app:shadowHeight="2dp"
                app:cornerRadius="2dp"
                />


            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id = "@+id/btnSetting"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width = "0dp"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:shadowEnabled="true"
                app:shadowHeight="2dp"
                app:cornerRadius="2dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id = "@+id/btnCalendar"
            android:text="Calendar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            app:buttonColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="2dp"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the logcat:

```
11-30 00:49:29.728 8159-8159/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.jackmills.urbansportsfitness, PID: 8159
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jackmills.urbansportsfitness/com.jackmills.urbansportsfitness.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                 at com.jackmills.urbansportsfitness.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6991)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
                                                 at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
                                                 at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                 at com.jackmills.urbansportsfitness.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6991) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have attempted to roll back my gradle to see if that helped but to no avail; I'm thinking it might have something to do with info.hoang8f.widget.FButton but I'm not sure what it could be.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you add any library related to that button? If not remove that button from your xml or use an existing ui button

Comment: I did yeah, ill post the library implementation when im back at my PC